# Passing property to components inside ng-content (properties which aren't available in the component where the markup lies)

Tags: angular, transclusion, angular2-ngcontent

I am trying to develop a carousel.

The desired end result should be that the developer would simply write the entire markup in one place (let's say in `app.component.html`) with only an `options` property and then, the carousel would take over.

Problem is that from `carousel.component` I need to set some properties on `carousel-item.component` (properties that `app.component` should have nothing to do with... but all the markup is in `app.component.html`).

How can I achieve this?

**`app.component.html:`**

```
<carousel [options]="myOptions">
    <carousel-item *ngFor="let item of items">
        <img [src]="item.image" alt="" />
    </carousel-item>
</carousel>

<hr />

<carousel [options]="myOptions2">
    <carousel-item *ngFor="let item of items">
        <img [src]="item.image" alt="" />
    </carousel-item>
</carousel>
```

**`carousel.component.html:`**

```
<div class="carousel-stage">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

**`carousel-item.component.html:`**

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the only solution is to go with `@ContentChildren()`

In my `carousel.component.ts`:

```
import { ContentChildren, ... } from '@angular/core';

// ...

export class CarouselComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @ContentChildren(ItemComponent) carouselItems;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.carouselItems.forEach((item: ItemComponent, currentIndex) => {
      // Do stuff with each item
      // Even call item's methods:
      item.setWidth(someComputedWidth);
      item.setClass(someClass);
    }
  }
}
```

Then, in `carousel-item.component.ts`:

```
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @HostBinding('style.width') itemWidth;
  @HostBinding('class') itemClass;
  @HostBinding('@fade') fadeAnimationState;


  setWidth(width) {
    this.itemWidth = width + 'px';
  }
  setClass(class) {
    this.itemClass = class;
  }
  setAnimationState(state) {
    this.fadeAnimationState = state;
  }
}
```

Apparently, I can even bind animation triggers with **@HostBinding**. I assumed @HostBingind() was designed to only work with the standard html attributes (style, class etc.), but it seems that I can actually bind anything (literally anything).

Does anybody have a better solution? Before I accept my own answer...

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. This is the right way to do it, IMO. For another somewhat similar reference, you can look at how the Ag-Grid team has used transclusion for column configurations: [ag-grid-angular component](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-angular/blob/master/src/agGridNg2.ts), [ag-grid-column component](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-angular/blob/master/src/agGridColumn.ts). `@ContentChildren` is used without `ng-content` to get and use the child elements for configuration.